# EfficientDet D0 512x512 image size

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

what is the best image size should I use for training an EfficientDet D0 512x512 for object detection.
I have image size varying from 500x500 to 2000x2000 is this okay for training the EfficientDet D0 512x512?

Comment: I assume the  link for EfficientDet is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09070.pdf

Comment: yes, I'm asking about the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the appendix of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09070.pdf, there is a section describing the image resolution for training.

Depending on the speed/performance trade-off, you may choose a smaller resolution for detecting your objects, like 640x640, or increase the resolution to 1024x1024 if you have smaller objects in size; regardless of the case, preserve the aspect ratio when you resize your image.

Comment: I assume your saying to upscale the images which are lesser than 640x640 and downscale the images which are greater than 640x640? (In my case there no tiny objects so considering 640x640 is an good option).

Comment: Yes, resize all to 640x640 in one iteration/training, and then to 1024x1024. And yes, smaller resolutions could yield also very good result provided there are no very small objects.